# How do I subset a dataframe based on the length of the dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Say for example the values for a certain column is a dictionary which can be of different lengths. How do I subset the dataframe rows such that the length of the dictionary is more than 1? 
I tried,

`more_than_1 = data[len(data["column_name"]) > 1]`

But it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply len to the column containing the dict, and boolean index on that.
df[df["column_name"].apply(len)>1]

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the length that is returned is the length of the string. For example the length is returned as 2 for the empty dictionary {}.